# Finding key(s) with most values in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, find, key, max

I'm working on a function where I need to find the keys (of artists names) in a dictionary that have the most values. Sometimes two keys have the same number of values and in that case I need to return a list of the artists names.

Example Dictionary:

```
{'M':[("One",1400,30.0, 20.5,"oil paint","Austria"),("Three",1430,100.0,102.0,"watercolor","France")],
        'P':[("Eight",1460, 225.0, 200.0, "fresco","Netherlands")],
        'U':[("Nine",1203,182.0, 957.0,"egg tempera","Italy"), ("Twelve",1200,76.2,101.6,"egg tempera","France")]
        }
```

For this dictionary since M and U have the most values (M has 2 and U has 2 while P only has 1) the function should return

```
artists_with_most_work(dictionary1())

['M', 'U']
```

How could I search for the number of values of each keys and return the ones that have the most? I figured using max() would be a good idea but I don't think I'm using it correctly in my current attempt below. Thanks to anyone who can help

Code:

```
def artist_with_most_work(db):
    matches = []
    for key, record_list in db.items():
        for record in record_list:
            if item in record: 
                max(db) = themax
            matches.append(themax)
        return matches
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to first find the maximum length, then return all keys that reference a list with that length:

```
def artist_with_most_work(db):
    maxcount = max(len(v) for v in db.values())
    return [k for k, v in db.items() if len(v) == maxcount]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def artist_with_most_work(db):
...     maxcount = max(len(v) for v in db.values())
...     return [k for k, v in db.items() if len(v) == maxcount]
...
>>> d1 = {'M':[("One",1400,30.0, 20.5,"oil paint","Austria"),("Three",1430,100.0,102.0,"watercolor","France")],
...       'P':[("Eight",1460, 225.0, 200.0, "fresco","Netherlands")],
...       'U':[("Nine",1203,182.0, 957.0,"egg tempera","Italy"), ("Twelve",1200,76.2,101.6,"egg tempera","France")]
...      }
>>> artist_with_most_work(d1)
['M', 'U']
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to sometimes return ['U', 'M'] instead of ['M', 'U'] when testing is it possible to sort this so it always does it in order? I tried doing maxcount.sort() but this doesnt work since its an int

Comment: You could use an OrderedDict, which will preserve the order of the elements as they are inserted. Nothing would change here other than defining db = OrderedDict() instead of db = {}. Other than that, you could sort the list by using sorted(maxcount), which should give you ['M', 'U']

Comment: @n00bprogrammer22: yes, because you passed in a dictionary, and a dictionary is an unordered data structure. If you need your keys in a specific order, load your data into a `collections.OrderedDict()` object.

Comment: Is there a way to sort the returned list in alphabetical order instead of the dictionary?

Comment: I came up with a crafty way to accomplish this without using OrderedDict and edited your code as it seems easier then using OrderedDict

Comment: @n00bprogrammer22 sure, just use the `sorted()` function on the list comprehension.

Comment: @n00bprogrammer22: there is no need to edit my answer; your question didn't specify you wanted the output to be sorted, and adding `sorted(...)` around the list comprehension is trivial enough.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the requirement to return all members of a tie, you have to keep track of all the possibilities.

```
def artist_with_most_work(db):
    keys_by_size = collections.defaultdict(list)
    maxsize = 0
    for key, recordlist in db.items():
        nitems = len(recordlist)
        keys_by_size[nitems].append(key)
        maxsize = max(maxsize, nitems)

    return keys_by_size[maxsize]
```